# Bootstrap estimate of $min_{i,j}(|X_i - X_j|)$

Tags: confidence-interval, bootstrap, standard-error

I have $n$ IID samples $X_i$ from some distribution. I can calculate $\min_{i \neq j}(|X_i - X_j|)$ and would like to get a confidence interval for said quantity.

Naive Bootstrap clearly makes no sense here. Let

$$
X^{\star}_1,\dots, X^{\star}_n
$$
a bootsrapped sample. Then, with high probability, there exist $k\neq l$ such that $X^{\star}_k =X^{\star}_l$ and then

$$
\min_{i\neq j}(|X^{\star}_i-X^{\star}_j|) = 0
$$

Is there a modification of the Bootstrap that handles this case except for the Jackknife? Is it OK to discard identical samples?

PS - I am not really interested in this statistic, I just use it to present a problem I am facing, where resampling the same measurements ruins the statistic.

Comment: If the distributions are continuous, $\min_{i \neq j}$ is equivalent to $\min_{x_i \neq x_j}$, which would justify the "discard identical samples" approach.

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/galenseilis/9ef90b510ba4ed51c3cc55e0ab692ecc) is a Python gist demoing the use of (leave-one-out) jackknifing and dropping duplicates